# Making less than or equal sign in psp.cls?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, journal-publishing

I'm trying to write an article using the [psp class](ftp://ftp.cambridge.org/pub/texarchive/journals/latex/psp-cls/unpacked/) for the journal Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Mathematical Society. How do I type a less than or equal sign? I usually just use `\le` or `\leq`, but it's not working for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A simple document such as `\documentclass{psp}\begin{document}$A\le B$\end{document}` shows the glyph for me. Please, add a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I wanted to be able use the less than or equal in the sample tex file psp2esam.tex, but I ran into the error ! 
Undefined control sequence.
l.70 $a \le
            b$

Answer (score 2):

There is a bad error in the `psp2esam.tex` file that loads `amsfonts` and then does

```
\let\le=\leqslant  \let\leq=\leqslant
\let\ge=\geqslant  \let\geq=\geqslant
```

The commands `\leqslant` and `\geqslant` are only defined if `amssymb` is loaded.

Much of the given preamble is completely useless nowadays, because *all* TeX distributions provide the files the code checks for existence. You can reduce it to

```
\documentclass{psp}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}

\let\le=\leqslant  \let\leq=\leqslant
\let\ge=\geqslant  \let\geq=\geqslant
\let\lessmuch=\ll
\providecommand\multpt{\,.\,}
\let\highmultpt=\cdot
\newcommand\bnabla{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}

% Define some 'Log-like' roman expressions
\newromanexpr\Hess{Hess}

% Define some shorthands for the Bibliography
\newcommand\JFM{\textit{J.~Fluid Mech.} }
\newcommand\PRSL{\textit{Proc. Roy. Soc. London, Ser. A} }
\newcommand\SAM{\textit{Stud. Appl. Math.} }

\newcommand\eqnomit{\mathrm{EQUATION\ OMITTED}}

\begin{document}

[...]
```

Comment: Oh interesting. Thanks a lot for your help! You made my day a lot better! I hope you have a good one!

Comment: It looks as if it might also work with the default settings of `unicode-math`, which defines all or almost all the symbols in `amssymb` and numerous other packages.

Comment: It's supposed to be declared, I think, in the `psp2esym.sty` package.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, `unicode-math` would override those redefinitions, because it does its job at begin document; but you would lose the slant in the symbols.

Comment: @egreg You are correct: you need to add `\renewcommand\le\leqslant`, etc., right after `\begin{document}` for it to work with `unicode-math`. (I’m sure there are more complex ways to put it in the preamble.) Also, `\bnabla` needs to be defined as`\mbfnabla`, `\symbf{\nabla}` or a few other alternatives. Or you could just use the names defined by `unicode-math`, redefining them if you need to compile with `amssymb` and `pifont`.